# Problem The document can not be opened with Design Automation

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-designautomation

I have an issue with extracting information of a big model include Revit link file. Before I tested with a small model, and it was working fine, but when I'm try with real project, it responds with *"The document can not be opened"*.

This is how it look like in BIM 360
[image]

This is how link loaded look like:

[image]

The result text output:

```json
{
  "status": "failedInstructions",
  "reportUrl": "https://dasprod-store.s3.amazonaws.com/workItem/chuong/e7f2350440e24f358f89de79a7c91907/report.txt?X-Amz-Expires=48600&X-Amz-Security-Token=IQoJb3JpZ2luX2VjEAgaCXVzLWVhc3QtMSJHMEUCIQDHc0FtF7DejMMwnJcs1qQcDHpKTO7rvsQl6UDmZ07mZgIgaRXfR8Wq0imG83H8Ul0E8PXEr2qDHIzmb0SgFogODPUqgAMIcRAEGgwyMjA0NzMxNTIzMTAiDCqPtFe9aUjRLZk2hCrdApcSY6tP4PjKxjjdhonzSdr0gKNB7sJuYDSqqij04o7kNFWCMn5orAJDBzlLck6w2J5vXmAubS%2BINiDV6o5hb3xGsE0Tqg8FNPTVtULgNcnIBfA6SJ8dWgYeDQQixb0DNv9O%2BEwfYWi6K0nJoLtviMHDbrHHOrD0oU82Sjil4kWk1Y4Gna7AgLYVJUbTmJdqvcEKez74RuceTI%2F9i0KF4fjq4jl5bZ%2FDJi8DbeWce78MCz2%2Bh8w%2F2Nzxy%2FktFt7fdXeODQ%2BLJNTzXp9m06kS1m8Y%2F1GKIZ17DJoz5PPUDFZ7KG4hl8fcGh2ciu%2F3BZScHRnEHrolIV24f%2BWH%2FrPP31QA68VYcpta2JiopdiHOD2LYyMz5xDbXUsXZxK77oU%2FfIP2tKU5sFUmlirG%2BWb2mMWozu1or2oonZhqTEIdk2Z1UWd9WnVmr4rw%2F04mu0HZroqySFb8PjyBrTRXPIw1LC7qwY6ngGOG7e8VdYs51o3wZQWJgtHrizAeoRLTL1bkHyi3o%2FjuawRCj26t7XaQqqRwHcaqq799HrM0p07c2cWpPNYwU0yVmNUPAkSgzNfnXJYiCWJRKfsUOcwmw%2FLZiEcVVhmxUCRFlyMsquhtiB5SLNdMuYQzHQYnpMXZvlH%2F8nMcBWThZLeE7nv1DJ3%2FcY1TgxBeynlCV%2B%2BL3LZGXNkUhjOw%3D%3D&X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential=ASIATGVJZKM3A25O6ZXA%2F20231205%2Fus-east-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Date=20231205T094743Z&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&X-Amz-Signature=571a7fc19e90b786a0b37056c222b03191905d1326640ea9056810eb254c5e58",
  "stats": {
    "timeQueued": "2023-12-05T09:47:43.822186Z",
    "timeDownloadStarted": "2023-12-05T09:47:43.9878169Z",
    "timeInstructionsStarted": "2023-12-05T09:48:23.063894Z",
    "timeInstructionsEnded": "2023-12-05T09:48:39.6756967Z",
    "bytesDownloaded": 1643282025
  },
  "id": "e7f2350440e24f358f89de79a7c91907"
}
```

Report issue text file:

```
[12/05/2023 09:37:23] Job information:
{
  "CommandLine": [
    "$(engine.path)\\\\revitcoreconsole.exe /i \"$(args[inputFile].path)\" /al \"$(appbundles[ExtractRoomApp].path)\""
  ],
  "Settings": {
    "script": {},
    "dasOpenNetwork": {
      "value": "true",
      "isEnvironmentVariable": true
    }
  },
  "Id": "5364405261db4fcab7390912311e1a12",
  "ActivityId": "chuong.ExtractRoomActivity+dev",
  "EngineId": "Autodesk.Revit_2022!111",
  "Apps": [
    "chuong.ExtractRoomApp!1"
  ],
  "BoundArguments": {
    "inputFile": {
      "localName": "$(inputFile)",
      "url": "https://developer.api.autodesk.com/Masked:5ExFkvl4kIUYxoDf5p1H6KVkfVc=",
      "headers": {
        "Authorization": "Masked:JZvFNdVezuuGzgPS++bx8BYmULM="
      }
    },
    "result": {
      "localName": "result.json",
      "url": "https://developer.api.autodesk.com/Masked:QncBiKhoDRMD7nneno7DNoKs2tQ=",
      "verb": "put"
    },
    "onComplete": {
      "ondemand": true,
      "optional": true,
      "url": "https://webhook.site/Masked:jj4Cb6+4JjGSYX7ds6SH7v3J46Q=",
      "verb": "post"
    }
  },
  "Quotas": {
    "limitProcessingTimeSec": 10800,
    "limitTotalUncompressedAppsSizeInMB": 5000
  }
}
[12/05/2023 09:37:23] Starting work item 5364405261db4fcab7390912311e1a12
[12/05/2023 09:37:24] Start download phase.
[12/05/2023 09:37:24] Start downloading input: verb - 'GET', url - 'https://developer.api.autodesk.com/oss/v2/buckets/wip.dm.prod/objects/443c8464-a70c-4009-9140-0e41cd761f5b.rvt'
[12/05/2023 09:38:02] End downloading file. Source=https://developer.api.autodesk.com/oss/v2/buckets/wip.dm.prod/objects/443c8464-a70c-4009-9140-0e41cd761f5b.rvt,LocalFile=T:\Aces\Jobs\5364405261db4fcab7390912311e1a12\28510851-3eb3-4b10-a8cc-e9f00ee3a068.zip,BytesDownloaded=1643282025,Duration=38845ms
[12/05/2023 09:38:02] End download phase successfully.
[12/05/2023 09:38:02] Start preparing script and command line parameters.
[12/05/2023 09:38:02] Command line: [ /i "T:\Aces\Jobs\5364405261db4fcab7390912311e1a12\28510851-3eb3-4b10-a8cc-e9f00ee3a068.zip" /al "T:\Aces\Applications\1f8c88d4b80171baeef657f5c0c83184.chuong.ExtractRoomApp[1].package"]
[12/05/2023 09:38:02] End preparing script and command line parameters.
[12/05/2023 09:38:02] Start script phase.
[12/05/2023 09:38:02] Start Revit Core Engine standard output dump.
[12/05/2023 09:38:03] ====== Revit is running: revitcoreconsole ======
[12/05/2023 09:38:03] Current Exe path: T:\Aces\AcesRoot\22.0\coreEngine\Exe\revitcoreconsole.exe
[12/05/2023 09:38:03] Echoing command line args:
[12/05/2023 09:38:03]   0:/i
[12/05/2023 09:38:03]   1:T:\Aces\Jobs\5364405261db4fcab7390912311e1a12\28510851-3eb3-4b10-a8cc-e9f00ee3a068.zip
[12/05/2023 09:38:03]   2:/al
[12/05/2023 09:38:03]   3:T:\Aces\Applications\1f8c88d4b80171baeef657f5c0c83184.chuong.ExtractRoomApp[1].package
[12/05/2023 09:38:03]   4:/isolate
[12/05/2023 09:38:03]   5:HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\AppDataLow\Software\Autodesk\CoreUser\WorkItem_5364405261db4fcab7390912311e1a12
[12/05/2023 09:38:03]   6:T:\Aces\Jobs\5364405261db4fcab7390912311e1a12\userdata
[12/05/2023 09:38:03] Selected Revit\RCE install Path: (from app.config)
[12/05/2023 09:38:03] Resolving location of Revit/RevitCoreEngine installation...
[12/05/2023 09:38:03] Loading RCE ....
[12/05/2023 09:38:08] Running user application....
[12/05/2023 09:38:08] Found an addIn for registration: Autodesk.Forge.Sample.RoomExtractor.addin
[12/05/2023 09:38:08] Language not specified, using English-United States(ENU) as default.
[12/05/2023 09:38:11] Get RCE: (VersionBuild) 22.1.50.7 (VersionNumber) 2022 (SubVersionNumber) 2022.1.5
[12/05/2023 09:38:11] Autodesk.Revit.Exceptions.InvalidOperationException: The document can not be opened.
[12/05/2023 09:38:11]    at Autodesk.Revit.ApplicationServices.Application.OpenDocumentFile(ModelPath modelPath, OpenOptions openOptions)
[12/05/2023 09:38:11]    at DesignAutomationFramework.DesignAutomationData..ctor(Application revitApp, String mainModelPath)
[12/05/2023 09:38:11]    at DesignAutomationFramework.DesignAutomationReadyEventArgs..ctor(Application revitApp, String mainModelPath)
[12/05/2023 09:38:11]    at DesignAutomationFramework.DesignAutomationBridge.SetDesignAutomationReady(Application revitApp, String mainModelPath)
[12/05/2023 09:38:11]    at RevitCoreEngineTest.RceConsoleApplication.Program.UserMain(CommandLineArgs cl)
[12/05/2023 09:38:17] RESULT: Failure - Result of running user app is failure
[12/05/2023 09:38:17] Finished running.  Process will return: TestError
[12/05/2023 09:38:17] ====== Revit finished running: revitcoreconsole ======
[12/05/2023 09:38:18] End Revit Core Engine standard output dump.
[12/05/2023 09:38:18] Error: Application revitcoreconsole.exe exits with code 4 which indicates an error.
[12/05/2023 09:38:18] End script phase.
[12/05/2023 09:38:18] Error: An unexpected error happened during phase CoreEngineExecution of job.
[12/05/2023 09:38:19] Job finished with result FailedExecution
[12/05/2023 09:38:19] Job Status:
{
  "status": "failedInstructions",
  "reportUrl": "https://dasprod-store.s3.amazonaws.com/workItem/chuong/5364405261db4fcab7390912311e1a12/report.txt?X-Amz-Expires=48600&X-Amz-Security-Token=IQoJb3JpZ2luX2VjEAgaCXVzLWVhc3QtMSJHMEUCIQDHc0FtF7DejMMwnJcs1qQcDHpKTO7rvsQl6UDmZ07mZgIgaRXfR8Wq0imG83H8Ul0E8PXEr2qDHIzmb0SgFogODPUqgAMIcRAEGgwyMjA0NzMxNTIzMTAiDCqPtFe9aUjRLZk2hCrdApcSY6tP4PjKxjjdhonzSdr0gKNB7sJuYDSqqij04o7kNFWsCMn5orAJDBzlLck6w2J5vXmAubS%2BINiDV6o5hb3xGsE0Tqg8FNPTVtULgNcnIBfA6SJ8dWgYeDQQixb0DNv9O%2BEwfYWi6K0nJoLtviMHDbrHHOrD0oU82Sjil4kWk1Y4Gna7AgLYVJUbTmJdqvcEKez74RuceTI%2F9i0KF4fjq4jl5bZ%2FDJi8DbeWce78MCz2%2Bh8w%2F2Nzxy%2FktFt7fdXeODQ%2BLJNTzXp9m06kS1m8Y%2F1GKIZ17DJoz5PPUDFZ7KG4hl8fcGh2ciu%2F3BZScHRnEHrolIV24f%2BWH%2FrPP31QA68VYcpta2JiopdiHOD2LYyMz5xDbXUsXZxK77oU%2FfIP2tKU5sFUmlirG%2BWb2mMWozu1or2oonZhqTEIdk2Z1UWd9WnVmr4rw%2F04mu0HZroqySFb8PjyBrTRXPIw1LC7qwY6ngGOG7e8VdYs51o3wZQWJgtHrizAeoRLTL1bkHyi3o%2FjuawRCj26t7XaQqqRwHcaqq799HrM0p07c2cWpPNYwU0yVmNUPAkSgzNyfnXJYiCWJRKfsUOcwmw%2FLZiEcVVhmxUCRFlyMsquhtiB5SLNdMuYQzHQYnpMXZvlH%2F8nMcBWThZLeE7nv1DJ3%2FcY1TgxBeynlCV%2B%2BL3LZGXNkUhjOw%3D%3D&X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential=ASIATGVJZKM3A25O6ZXA%2F20231205%2Fus-east-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Date=20231205T093723Z&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&X-Amz-Signature=d44ea4b445a0e866378019f41fe96cf350ac36cba7cd88bbac5681f6b0e3516e",
  "stats": {
    "timeQueued": "2023-12-05T09:37:23.7656418Z",
    "timeDownloadStarted": "2023-12-05T09:37:23.889598Z",
    "timeInstructionsStarted": "2023-12-05T09:38:02.8475949Z",
    "timeInstructionsEnded": "2023-12-05T09:38:18.9165214Z",
    "bytesDownloaded": 1643282025
  },
  "id": "5364405261db4fcab7390912311e1a12"
}
```

Comment: _"Dear Autodesk Forge Team."_, Stack Overflow is not customer support for Autodesk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your workitem argument is incorrect.

```js
"inputFile": {
      "localName": "$(inputFile)",
      "url": "https://developer.api.autodesk.com/...",
      "headers": {
        "Authorization": "...."
      }
    },
    "result": {
      "localName": "result.json",
      "url": "https://developer.api.autodesk.com/...",
      "verb": "put"
    },
```

For a ZIP package, it should be like the example below. Revit doesn't support opening a ZIP file directly. Your original Activity and Workitm config would be something like `revit.exe "T:\Aces\Jobs\5364405261db4fcab7390912311e1a12\28510851-3eb3-4b10-a8cc-e9f00ee3a068.zip"` in Windows using the command line.

Please see https://aps.autodesk.com/blog/localname-pathinzip-zip

```js
"inputFile": {
      "localName": "$(inputFile)",
      "url": "https://developer.api.autodesk.com/...",
      "pathInZip": "root.rvt", //!<<<< the root filename 
      "headers": {
        "Authorization": "...."
      }
    },
    "result": {
      "localName": "result.json",
      "url": "https://developer.api.autodesk.com/...",
      "verb": "put"
    },
```

And please refer to this blog post to check if your Revit model is a composite RCW design by checking if the version extension has `"isCompositeDesign": true`.

https://aps.autodesk.com/blog/make-composite-revit-design-work-design-automation-api-revit

Comment: Hi @Eason Kang, I don't think it is reason, my process working normal now with medium (100mb -500mb)model, it just failed with model linked with another revit file I raised issue (1.5GB).

Comment: This is log with normal model :
https://gist.github.com/chuongmep/7492230ca3d08984d11d7be44fc26693

Comment: Hi @ChuongHo, it's nothing related to the file size. I replied to https://gist.github.com/chuongmep/7492230ca3d08984d11d7be44fc26693?permalink_comment_id=4784154#gistcomment-4784154

Comment: Could you try downloading the source file of the not-working one from ACC Web UI to see if ACC will give you a ZIP or a single Revit file?

Comment: yes, it give me a zip file, can give me a example with workitem job C# ?

Comment: There is no big difference in the code. All you need is to specify the root Revit filename by specifying the [PathInZip](https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/forge-api-dotnet-design.automation/blob/d03f931042ae505d8eb94f033a91f5434fa24466/src/Autodesk.Forge.DesignAutomation/Model/XrefTreeArgument.gen.cs#L59) in the workitem

Comment: Before submitting the workitem, you will need to get the root file name by `compositeParentFile` value, according to https://aps.autodesk.com/blog/make-composite-revit-design-work-design-automation-api-revit

Comment: And you can find which C# function wraps the API endpoint here: https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/forge-api-dotnet-client#api-documentation

Comment: is it compositeParrentFile always is name file response by hook event ?

Comment: It make me a issue :Cannot implicitly convert type 'Autodesk.Forge.DesignAutomation.Model.XrefTreeArgument' to 'string'
 https://gist.github.com/chuongmep/fdb21e3e883e0d52248a42e170720d17